# Turn simple WordPress title script into a PHP function

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have this `PHP` code to construct the contents of my WordPress `<title>` tag:

```
<?php
    global $page, $paged;
    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if($paged >= 2 || $page >= 2) {
        echo sprintf(__('Page %s', 'theme-name'), max( $paged, $page ) ).' | ';
    }
    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
    // Add the blog name.
    bloginfo( 'name' ); 
?>
```

Which, if on for example Page 2 of the list of posts, returns:

> Page 2 | Completed Projects | Website Name

**QUESTION**

How can I turn the `PHP` above into a `function` that returns a variable `$pageTitle` so that I can reuse this string throughout the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    global $page, $paged;
    // Add a page number if necessary:
    $pageTitle = '';
    if($paged >= 2 || $page >= 2) {
        $pageTitle .= sprintf(__('Page %s', 'theme-name'), max( $paged, $page ) ).' | ';
    }
    $pageTitle .= wp_title( '|', false, 'right' );
    // Add the blog name.
    $pageTitle .= get_bloginfo( 'name' );
```

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress is a mess and has different ways to either just echo to the screen or return info.

All of this is in this [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/)

For title use `wp_title( '|', false )`;

For bloginfo use `get_bloginfo( 'name' )`;

You can then use these and wrap a function around the entire thing.

Comment: This doesn't include everything I want to do in my question.

Comment: @AdamD Yes it does, and if you down voted, me you're ridiculous.

Comment: This does not append the Paging method invoked in my question. Am I missing something?